# Sketch uploading error in NodeMCU

Tags: azure, arduino, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I'm using Arduino IDE to upload a sketch to a NodeMCU ESP8266. This code worked fine the first time and I uploaded other code and then when I tried to upload again this happened.

There's no error message so I don't know what is the problem? I tried another sketch and it works. Did someone solve this kind of problem?

I was trying to upload [this repo](https://github.com/gloveboxes/Arduino-ESP8266-Secure-Http-Azure-IoT-Hub-Client).

> Archiving built core (caching) in: C:\Users\jinWook\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_21168\core\core_esp8266_esp8266_nodemcuv2_CpuFrequency_80,UploadSpeed_9600,FlashSize_4M3M_f08bb15d767fac8e618bccb270dc611d.a
>   Sketch uses 296925 bytes (28%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
>   Global variables use 41140 bytes (50%) of dynamic memory, leaving 40780 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
>   Uploading 301072 bytes from C:\Users\jinWook\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_399920/AzureClient.ino.bin to flash at 0x00000000
>   ........................................................................ [ 27% ]
>   ................................................................................ [ 54% ]
>   ................................................................................ [ 81% ]
>   .....................An error occurred while uploading the sketch

Answer (score -1):

i just increase the upload speed at 256000 and for me it solved the problem